# Sequelize.js transactions not rolling back

Tags: node.js, sequelize.js

Hi got a question of sequelize js and transactions.
So what i am trying to do is nest inserts and commit on success, rollback otherwise here is a snippet which isn't working for me for some reason or another.

```
sequelize()
    .transaction(function(t){
        myModel
            .create({
                name: 'shawn;
            }, {transaction: t})
            .success(function(newModel) {
                myModel
                    .create({
                        name: 'shawn;
                    }, {transaction: t})
                    .success(function(newModel) { t.commit()})
                    .error(function(err) {t.rollback()})
            }
            .error(function(err) {t.rollback()});
       });
```

Don't mind any syntax error the logic which i am looking to debug. The problem occurs when i replace the commit statement on success with a rollback i dont get the 2 inserts rows rolled back?

Regards
Shawn

Comment: for some unkown reason its working know must have had some sort of typo

Answer (score 1, accepted):

debug this, if error exist, you see message in console and rollback is run, else ...

```
sequelize()
.transaction(function(t){


    myModel.create({name: 'shawn'}).success(function(newModel) {

        console.log('success1')
        myModel.create({name: 'shawn'})
            .success(function(newModel){
                console.log('success2');
                t.commit();
            })
            .error(function(err){
                console.log('error2')
                t.rollback();
            });

    }).error(function(err) {
        console.log('error1')
        t.rollback()
    });
});
```